# next build throws error related to webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

When i run next build i get following error:

```
./node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/layers-2x.png
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)


> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:397:19
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/app/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:60:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/app/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:77:25)
#
```

my `next.config.js` seems to be configured to process `.png` files. Project uses leaflet and react-leaflet libraries. Error says nothing about images that I put in /public/images

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');
const theme = require('./app/styles/antdoverrides');

module.exports = {
    webpackDevMiddleware: (config) => {
        config.watchOptions = {
            poll: 800,
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
        };
        return config;
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {},
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that's triggering the error?

Answer (score 0):

One common issue with using react leaflet with nexjs is that it will not work with ssr. Are you loading your leaflet component in with dynamic?

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import React from "react";
import { LeafletMapProps } from "src/components/Map/Leaflet/LeafletMap";
import { LeafletMarkerProps } from "src/components/Map/Leaflet/LeafletMarker";

// Load every leaflet component since they dont work with ssr
interface MapProps extends LeafletMapProps {}

const Map: React.FC<MapProps> = (props) => {
  const Map = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      dynamic(() => import("src/components/Map/Leaflet/LeafletMap"), {
        loading: () => <p>A map is loading</p>,
        ssr: false,
      }),
    []
  );
  return <Map {...props} />;
};

interface MarkerProps extends LeafletMarkerProps {}
const Marker: React.FC<MarkerProps> = (props) => {
  const Marker = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      dynamic(() => import("src/components/Map/Leaflet/LeafletMarker"), {
        ssr: false,
      }),
    []
  );
  return <Marker {...props} />;
};

export { Map, Marker };
```

Comment: that did not help